# How to open an app link in expo client app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have published my react native app using "expo publish" and sent a link to my app using "expo send" to my Email. When I click on the link, a web browser opens instead of the expo client app. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `expo send`, you are sending a link to your app on your localhost, not to the published app on the Expo server.  What you need to do is to open the link to the project page that is provided in the terminal after you executed `expo publish`.  It is in the form https://expo.io/@username/projectname?release-channel=staging.  On that web page there is an option to send a link to your mobile, which will open in the Expo Client App.